# Terraform AWS ClientVPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws, openvpn

I have existing AWS ClinetVPN and currently I'm adding route to this ClientVPN manually using AWS console.

I want to terraform this so I can add any new routes to the exiting AWS ClientVPN using terraform.

How can I use do this by Terraform? I dont have to create any new resources as all the resources already exist.

**Now that I have imported the resources**
I need to import one by one each route from clientVPN and add the definition in main.tf file before running `terraform plan`

In this way, if I have 20 route then I have to add 20 resource entry in main.tf file. Is there a way, I can just write only one entry and terraform will pick this maybe by using variable? I'm not sure, please help me with this.

Comment: Ok. What is your question or problem?

Comment: I have existing clientVPN running, Currently we are adding routes manually. We want to terraform it so no one can make manual changes.
Trying to follow this link. [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ec2_client_vpn_route)
How will terraform pick existing routes and how can I add new routes using terraform.

Comment: @Marcin any help from your end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either have to [import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/import.html) the required, pre-existing resources to TF, or pass values for `client_vpn_endpoint_id` and `target_vpc_subnet_id` as input parameters to your TF script.

Comment: Could you please help me with the link or doc I can refer because this is something new to me.

Comment: @TechhackNew I already provided the link to the `import`.

Comment: could you please help me with my latest comment.

Comment: @TechhackNew Sadly your question and comment are unclear. I would suggest making new question, with new details and any TF code you have written so far to solve the problem. Also, acceptance of my answer would be appreciated as it clearly helped you as you imported your resources.

Comment: added new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69174714/how-to-add-multiple-aws-clientvpn-routes-using-terraform